# Return first and last digits of an integer using while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I've been trying to write a program that uses a while loop to return the first and last digits entered.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FirstLastInt {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int fdig, ldig, num;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an Integer.");
    num = in.nextInt();

    ldig = num%10;

    while (num > 0)
    { fdig = num/10;
        num = num/10;

         System.out.println("The first digit is " + fdig + ", and the last digit is " + ldig + ".");
    }
}
```

num is the integer entered, fdig is to be the first digit, and ldig is to be the last digit.

I figured the last digit will always be num%10, and I realized so far using the while loop like it's written will return the first digit......Along with a bunch of other numbers I don't really need.

For example:

```
run:
Enter an Integer.
98884
The first digit is 9888, and the last digit is 4.
The first digit is 988, and the last digit is 4.
The first digit is 98, and the last digit is 4.
The first digit is 9, and the last digit is 4.
The first digit is 0, and the last digit is 4.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

It looks like the loop runs before and after I get the digit I want. Is there anyway to specify which line I'd like printed? (In the example, it's "The first digit is 9, and the last digit is 4.")

Comment: Why are you printing inside the while loop?

Comment: Put the `println` outside the while loop.

Comment: The variable fdig isn't initialized if println is outside the while loop. So I put it inside.

Comment: @NathanDaniels Then the solution is to initialize it, not to put the printout in a place that doesn't make sense! Once you get that ironed out then you're just left with the remaining problem of fixing the last digit logic (your second problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep using your own code to see how it can be achieved that way then change your while condition and take system print outside:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FirstLastInt {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int ldig, num;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an Integer.");
        num = in.nextInt();

        ldig = num % 10;

        // keep looping num until it is in the range of 0-9
        while (num >= 10) {
            num = num / 10;
        }
        //initialize fdig variable and set it equal to num, just to make things clearer
        int fdig = num;

        System.out.println("The first digit is " + fdig + ", and the last digit is " + ldig + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indicate what you changed to achieve the correct results as well as why this change was necessary. The way you have it now, it looks almost similar to the code posted by the OP

Comment: Since you haven't initialized fdig and your println is out of the loop, you may need to consider either initializing it our adding an extra fdig = num/10 prior to while.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `String.valueOf` which doesn't require a loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an Integer.");
int num = in.nextInt();

String numString = String.valueOf(num);
char first = numString.charAt(0);
char last = numString.charAt(numString.length() - 1);

System.out.println("The first digit is " + first + ", and the last digit is " + last);
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to diagnose the issue with their code rather than have a completely different solution handed to them.

Comment: @JasonC If it be a homework problem, then yes, if real world then I think there are better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

package com.chandan;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumoffirstandlast(78548));
}

public static int sumoffirstandlast(int number){
    int sum=0;
    if(number<0){
        return -1;
    }
    if(number<10){
        return number+number;
    }
    int first=number%10;
    while(number>0)
    {
        number=number/10;
        if(number<10)
        {
            int digit=number%10;
            sum=sum+digit;
        }

    }
    int sum1=sum+first;
    return sum1;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class q2_prototype3
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        double number = scan.nextDouble();
        char firstDigit = String.valueOf(number).charAt(0);
        double lastDigit = number%10;
    System.out.println("Number given: " + number );
    System.out.println("First digit: " + firstDigit);
    System.out.println("Last digit: " + lastDigit );
    }
}
```